# Не могу затянуть библиотеку для Golang (linux)

Tags: golang

Пытаюсь затянуть пакет для Go

`go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v6`

Получаю ответ

```
cannot find package "github.com/go-redis/redis/v6" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/go-redis/redis/v6 (from $GOROOT)
        /root/git_project/checker/golang/src/github.com/go-redis/redis/v6 (from $GOPATH)
```

Как пофиксить?

Спасибо

Comment: gopkg.in/go-redis/redis.v6 - это устаревшая версия, лучше будет использовать github.com/go-redis/redis/v8

Comment: Мне нужна именно эта. Слишком много хитромудрого кода на ей навязано

Comment: а если попробовать `go get github.com/go-redis/redis@v6.15.5` ?

Answer (score 0):

Для загрузки версии `6.15.9` можно сделать так:
`go get github.com/go-redis/redis@latest`

Если нужна версия ниже, то вместо `latest` указать необходимую версию `@6.x.x`